# Display GCP Compute instance count in Grafana using Stackdriver?

Tags: stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver

I would like to graph the number of running GCP compute instances ( and stopped if possible ) using Stackdriver via Grafana.

Looking at Stackdriver i can't see any metric that just gives these numbers and i can't see anyway of abusing the exposed metrics to get this data.

Is there a way to achieve this ? Or maybe Stackdriver is the wrong tool for this and another GCP source can be used in Grafana to plot this graph ?

Thanks

Comment: Interesting question. I think you're correct that there's no obvious way to count the instances. It's surprising. I'm going to ask a colleague.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Igor -- a software engineer on Stackdriver -- I have a proposed solution.

There is no direct metric for counting running or non-running instances.

However, you can use a reducer (aggregation) to count the number of metric streams.

You just need to identify a metric where there is one stream per VM:

- instance/cpu/reserved_cores
- instance/cpu/utilization <-- this doesn't work
- instance/uptime

https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/metrics_gcp#gcp-compute

- agent/memory_usage
- agent/uptime

https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/metrics_agent#agent-agent

**NB** Stopped instances don't emit metrics and so can't be measured (in this way)
**NB** 'utilization' doesn't work for this, I was incorrect.

---

***ADDITIONAL INFO***

Here is an example using uptime and reserved_cores. I added a 3rd instance to show that count increases. You must specify a reducer of count.

[image]

Here's the equivalent using APIs Explorer:

[image]

Replace `[[PROJECT-ID]]` with yours and revise the `startTime` and `endTime` values in the following URL to experience this for yourself:

https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#search/timeseries/m/monitoring/v3/monitoring.projects.timeSeries.list?name=projects%252F[[PROJECT-ID]]&aggregation.alignmentPeriod=60s&aggregation.crossSeriesReducer=REDUCE_COUNT&aggregation.perSeriesAligner=ALIGN_RATE&filter=metric.type%253D%2522compute.googleapis.com%252Finstance%252Fuptime%2522&interval.endTime=2019-03-12T23%253A59%253A59-08%253A00&interval.startTime=2019-03-12T00%253A00%253A00-08%253A00&_h=13&

Comment: thanks for the feedback but i already tried this solution and failed to find a aggregation that lets me count the occurrence of a returned metric.

So if i query `compute.googleapis.com/instance/uptime` and groupBy `instance_name` then in theory i could count the result.... but how to do this ? It doesn't seem possible.

Comment: I revised the answer to include an example. You want to use a reducer (`COUNT`). `groupBy` will reduce the number of streams counted.

Comment: ok thanks.. i can confirm this works ( i had actually tried this ) but the Grafana StackDriver plugin enforces the metric type so prevents this from being usable in Grafana. For example when i use Uptime... the raw data back has a count of 160 but it axis unit is hard set to `seconds` so actually graphs 160/60 = 2.6 minutes.

Comment: That's good feedback. I recommend you submit that to Google through the public issue tracker: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187228&template=1162638